# Why I'm getting this exception: Assertion failed: Can't happen, cause we filter out systems which radiosity hashes are not in LightmapSettings

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What does it mean ? How can I fix it ?
Tried to goolge but didn't find any results about it.

[image: Exception]

Comment: Well, clearly that can't happen. (i.e. you have a bug and it should be reported as such).

Comment: Copy / backup, take away bits until the exception stops, add bits back until it re-appears, the last added bits are the cause.  Report the bug unless it's your own fault.